# Wordpress "Dynamic Featured Image": blank slider/gallery with HTTPS admin panel

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

I'm using "Dynamic Featured Image" to create a gallery inside a custom post.
All worked fine until I decided to buy and enable an SSL certificate for my Wordpress site. From that moment on, all the new galleries/image-sliders created displays nothing, blank, but all the old ones keep going just fine. If I disable the HTTPS on admin side, dis-link the images from the post and re-link them all, everything works.

It seems there's something wrong going on when the path of images is an https one. I'm running out of ideas. Anyone has some tips for me?

P.S.
I tried to apply this function to the plugins url request but had no luck.

```
function de_https ($url) {
    $url = preg_replace("/^https:/i", "http:", $url);
    return $url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This issue](https://github.com/ankitpokhrel/Dynamic-Featured-Image/issues/34) was fixed in [ver3.1.13](https://github.com/ankitpokhrel/Dynamic-Featured-Image/releases/tag/v3.1.13).